# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. NOT USING TWO RESPONSES

Tags: javascript, express, http-headers

JUST WANTED TO ASK

[image: I have this function that is called from the router]

[image: this is middleware that is executed before the previous function]

after hitting the entry-point I had this error message

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\mmeeee\Desktop\REACT_APP\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\mmeeee\Desktop\REACT_APP\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\mmeeee\Desktop\REACT_APP\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
    at C:\Users\mmeeee\Desktop\REACT_APP\backend\controllers\userController.js:27:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I tried to replace res.json with res.end but it seems not to be the problem right here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that `protected` middleware, you are invoking `next`, which could have the side effect of sending the response to the client, in the `try` block. You are also sending the response to the client in the `catch` block. After either of those blocks have executed, you should not try to modify the response further, which you do if you end up without a `token`. A potential refactoring:

```
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
  ) {
    try {
      const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
      if (!token) throw 'No token!'
      const decoded = theCodeYouWrote(token);
      req.user = await theCodeYouWroteForTheUser(decoded);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(401).json(...);
      return;
    }
  }
  next();
```